# Parameterized Junit test on Android with NULL parameter

Tags: java, android, android-studio, junit, android-testing

I am trying to write a JUNIT test with Parameterized test runner on android. 
When i run it as part of AndroidTest in Android Studio it give me following error for first test:

> ExampleTEst: Trying to set intVal with the value null that is not the
>   right type (String instead of Integer).

But when i run the same code as simple JUNIT test ( under android test in Android Studio) , it works fine.

Here is complete code of the example :

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;

import static junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals;


@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class ExampleTEst {

    @Parameterized.Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> params() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{

                {//Test # 0 :

                        null,
                        "JOJO"

                }
                ,
                {//Test # 1 :

                        1,
                        null

                }
        });
    }

    @Parameterized.Parameter
    public Integer intVal;
    @Parameterized.Parameter(value = 1)
    public String StringVal;

    public static final Object[] resultsObjs = {null, "JOJO", 1, null};
    public static int counter = 0;

    @Test
    public void aTest() {

        assertEquals((Integer) resultsObjs[counter], intVal);
        assertEquals((String) resultsObjs[counter + 1], StringVal);

        counter += 2;


    }
}
```